# Tensorboard page is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tf.keras

I'm using tensorflow 2.4.1 and tensorboard 2.4.1 in centos 6.5
I'm trying to track a keras model undergoing training using a tensorboard call back, but I'm always getting a blank page when I start the tensorboard localhost server.

The main part of my code is copied from the "[Image classification from scratch](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/)" tutorial in keras.io website, so I will not paste it here. I will add the parts that I changed to include this callback into the code.

Here is my code for the call functions:

```
myCallbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=2),
    tfa.callbacks.TQDMProgressBar(),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='ep{epoch:03d}-loss{loss:.3f}.h5',monitor='loss', save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, period=3),
    TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs',profile_batch=0)
]
```

and this is the code for model training:

```
model.fit(x=testData, epochs=epochs, verbose=2,validation_data=valData,callbacks=myCallbacks)
model.save('myModel.h5')
quit()
```

I'm invoking the training code from linux shell, like this:

```
python -m train.py
```

Similarly, I am invoking tensorboard using this line from linux shell:

```
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir /path/logs
```

which yields something like this in terminal:

```
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.4.1 at http://localhost:6007/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I open the URL `http://localhost:6007/` inside firefox I get a blank page [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDB18.png).

Here's the page source as per firefox view source:
[image: here]

I tried changing ports, but it didn't help

I've also tried using `load_ext tensorboard` but that line was not recognized in my shell nor in python command prompt.

I've been debugging this for a couple of days now and failed to resolve it. Appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 if that would make any difference

Comment: Use `python -m tensorboard.main --inspect --logdir /path/logs` on the command line. Is there any results shown for `Event statistics` and `num_steps`?